# convergence of $\sum_n x_n$ versus $\sum_n f(x_n)$ for differentiable $f$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $f(0) = 0$, $f$ is differentiable at 0, $f'(0) \ne 0$, and $x_n \rightarrow 0$. What can we say about (i) the convergence of $\sum_n x_n$ versus (ii) the convergence of $\sum_n f(x_n)$?

It seems that (i) implies (ii) and my reasoning is as follows. By the definition of derivative, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left( \frac{f(x)}{x} - f(0) \right) = 0$. Let $\epsilon = \left| \frac{f'(0)}{2} \right| > 0$. By the definition of limit, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in B(0, \delta)$, $\left| \frac{f(x)}{x} - f'(0) \right| < \epsilon$. Therefore for $x \in B(0, \delta)$, $\frac{1}{2}f'(0) x \le f(x) \le \frac{3}{2}f'(0) x$ and for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $x_n \in B(0, \delta)$ if $n > N$. So $\frac{1}{2}f'(0) \sum_{n > N} x_n = \sum_{n > N} \frac{1}{2}f'(0) x_n \le \sum_{n > N} f(x_n) \le \sum_{n > N} \frac{3}{2}f'(0) x_n = \frac{3}{2}f'(0) \sum_{n > N} x_n$.

It also seems that (ii) implies (i) by a similar argument. Specifically, $f$ must be strictly monotone in some open set $U$ containing 0 and we can apply the argument above to $(f\restriction_U)^{-1}$.

Is my reasoning right?

Comment: What theorem are you using to know that there exists a positive integer $N$ so that $\frac{1}{2}f'(0)x \leq f(x) \leq 2f'(0)x$

Comment: I am using the definition of derivative, which is that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left( \frac{f(x)}{x} - f'(0) \right) = 0$, and therefore that for $\epsilon = \left| \frac{f'(0)}{2} \right| > 0$, there is a $\delta$ for which if $x \in B(0, \delta)$, $\left| \frac{f(x)}{x} - f'(0) \right| < \epsilon$. Then set $U = B(0, \delta)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Specifically, $f$ must be strictly monotone in some open set $U$ containing $0$

No, it need not be. Unless you require continuous differentiability. Consider, for some $0 < c < \frac{1}{2}$, the function

$$f(x) = c\cdot x + \int_0^x \sin \tfrac{1}{t}\,dt.$$

$f$ is differentiable on all of $\mathbb{R}$, with $f'(0) = c\neq 0$, and $f'(x) = c + \sin \frac{1}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$. Then $f'$ changes sign infinitely often in every neighbourhood of $0$.

It is straightforward to see that an $f$ with your properties preserves absolute convergence, i.e. $\sum x_n$ converges absolutely if and only if $\sum f(x_n)$ converges absolutely, but for conditional convergence, even the harmless

$$f(x) = x + x^2$$

converts the conditionally convergent series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}}$$

into the divergent series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{n}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you for your correction and examples. I am willing to take on the assumption that f is continuously differentiable, in which case it seems that my conclusion is true.

Comment: For the preservation of absolute convergence, differentiability of $f$ in $0$ with $f'(0)\neq 0$ is enough. $f$ need not be differentiable, nor even continuous, anywhere else for that to hold. For the preservation of conditional convergence, the example $f(x) = x + x^2$ shows that even analyticity is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the given proof to follow, we must assume that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is eventually monotone.

Without loss of generality we shall assume that $f'(0)>0$ and $x_n>0$ for $n=1,2,\ldots \,$ .

Since $\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim}\frac{f(x_n)}{x_n} = f'(0)$, there is a positive integer $N$ so that

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} f'(0) \, x_n<f(x_n)<\frac{3}{2} f'(0) \, x_n \; \text{   whenever  } \; n \geq N \, .
\end{equation}

Suppose $\sum_n x_n$ converges. Then $\sum_n \frac{3}{2} f'(0) \, x_n = \frac{3}{2} f'(0)\sum_n x_n$ also converges. Since we eventually have $f(x_n)<\frac{3}{2} f'(0) \, x_n$, and given that a finite number of terms of a series do not affect convergence, the series $\sum_n f(x_n)$ converges by the comparison test.

Suppose $\sum_n x_n$ diverges. Then $\sum_n \frac{1}{2} f'(0) \, x_n = \frac{1}{2} f'(0)\sum_n x_n$ also diverges. Since we eventually have $\frac{1}{2} f'(0) \, x_n<f(x_n)$, the series $\sum_n f(x_n)$ diverges by the comparison test.

Comment: That only works if $\sum x_n$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Yes sorry, this assumes both series are positive term series.